# Fractional nonlinear Schrodinger equation ... looking for cnoidal solution

Tags: differential-equations

I need to solve the following gnarly differential equation (a version of fractional nonlinear Schrödinger equation):

```
q = 3/2.;
a = 0.0001;
sol = NDSolveValue[{(1 - x^(-q)/Gamma[1 - q]) u[x] - (q x^(1 - q))/Gamma[2 - 
q] u'[x] - (q (q - 1) x^(2 - q))/(2 Gamma[3 - q]) u''[x] - 2 (u[x])^2 u[x] == 0,
u[a] == 1,
u'[a] == 0},
u[x], {x, a, 100}]
```

Due to there being $x^{-q}$ in the equation, $x > 0$. However, my initial condition is defined in terms of $x = 0$ so the way I fix it is by closely approaching the origin from the right at $x = a$.

Then I plot the solution and look at it. Here's the problem: the solution changes as I make `a` smaller and smaller. It makes me worried that whatever *Mathematica* is getting is not convergent, but perhaps the problem is not well-posed either.

The reason is that the solution is supposed to be like a cnoidal wave (whose shape is a function of `q`), which develops an undefined first slope `u'[x]` at the origin. Since the first derivative should be undefined, then it is debilitating to specify it in the `NDSolve` command. The solution is also supposed to go to 1 at $x = 0$ but as I vary `a`, the solution seems to diverge in the region $a \leq x \leq 0.02$. From my basic understanding of the problem, the solution should start at 1 and decay from there.

Has anyone ran into this problem before (maybe in fluid simulations)? I'm not sure how to address these problems in *Mathematica*.

Comment: "Since the first derivative should be undefined..." - `NDSolve[]` will definitely have trouble. Recall that it uses piecewise polynomials for interpolation, and that polynomials have never had a vertical slope. Consider factoring out the singular behavior so that you have a solution that can be approximated by piecewise polynomials, and then multiply that isolated factor with the resulting interpolant?

Comment: Another problem I see is that if you take your pde, multiply it by sqrt[x] to get rid of the singularity at x=0, and then set x to 0 in the resulting pde, you get u[0] = 0.  So the pde wants u[0] = 0, and you are forcing u[a] to be 1 as a approaches 0, making instability expected.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you really need to use a small `a` to see what is going on with this system.

```
pde = (1 - x^(-q)/Gamma[1 - q]) u[x] - (q x^(1 - q))/Gamma[2 - q] u'[x] -
(q (q - 1) x^(2 - q))/(2 Gamma[3 - q]) u''[x] - 
       2 (u[x])^2 u[x] == 0;
```

Use your values for u and a fairly small a.

```
q = 3/2
a = 10^-11
Clear[u]
```

Increase `WorkingPrecision` and `MaxSteps` such that

```
sol = NDSolve[{pde2, u[a] == 1, u'[a] == 0}, u[x], {x, a, 200}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 40, MaxSteps -> 500000];

u[x_] = u[x] /. sol[[1]]

strg = {"a=", N[a]}[[1]] + {"a=", N[a]}[[2]];
Plot[u[x], {x, a, 200}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotLabel -> strg]
```

[image]

Its a little hard to see, but for small `x`, `u` oscillates about `u = 0` and then jogs to oscillating about a positive `u`.  I won't show it here, but if I change to `a = 10^-12`, the oscillations jog to a negative `u`.
Check when `a` becomes really small:

```
q = 3/2
a = 10^-22
Clear[u]

sol = NDSolve[{pde2, u[a] == 1, u'[a] == 0}, u[x], {x, a, 200}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 40, MaxSteps -> 500000];

u[x_] = u[x] /. sol[[1]]

strg = {"a=", N[a]}[[1]] + {"a=", N[a]}[[2]];
Plot[u[x], {x, a, 200}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, PlotLabel -> strg]
```

[image]

In this case, the oscillations remain about `u = 0` until around `x = 150`
This may be the behavior you are after.  Smaller values of `a` are possible, but NDSolve starts failing for this system when WorkingPrecision gets too high.
Looking at the behavior near 0:

```
Plot[u[x], {x, a, 2 a}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> strg]
```

[image]

This shows that of `u'[0]==0` at `x = a`, at least by eyeball.  The next plot shows why getting rid of the singularity by multiplying the pde by `x^3/2` does not help.
[image]

This shows a huge peak at small `x`, but still a positive `x`.  The closer to zero `a` gets, the higher the peak, which is evidently why NDSolve reports an infinity for the equation with the singularity removed and using `a = 0`.
It is also true that if you remove the singularity from the pde, solving the subsequent pde for `u''[x]` still has `x^2` in the denominator.